# Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Interop.MicroPoint_IP_RealTime'

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

Estou com o **ERRO** abaixo ao executar o projeto em Debug(em Release funciona normalmente):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in Slim.exe
>
> Additional information: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly
>   'Interop.MicroPoint_IP_RealTime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' ou uma de suas dependências. O sistema não pode
>   encontrar o arquivo especificado.

Podem me ajudar?

[image: print do erro]

Comment: Dica 1: Entre nas propriedades desta DLL no Explorer do Windows, botão direito -> propriedades e veja se este arquivo não está bloqueado (motivo para isso é vc ter baixado o arquivo da internet).

Comment: Dica 2: Exclua a referencia desta DLL e inclua de novo. Dê clean e build na solution.

Comment: Ou Deleta a Pasta Debug, Limpa o Projeto e executa novamente, parece ser estranho, mas já aconteceu comigo

Comment: Dica 1: verifiquei e o arquivo não esta bloqueado.
Dica 2: ja tinha feito isso mas fiz novamente e continuou com o mesmo erro.
Após limpar a pasta Debug, limpar o projeto e executar novamente o erro continua e não funciona mais em Release.
Mais alguma possibilidade?